# What encoding is the device token for APNs in?

Tags: notifications, push, device, token, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to get the Device Token returned from the application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken method? Since I'm not very good at PHP, I'd like for my user to manually enter the token into a program on their computer that is going to be used to send out the notification. But, I can't get the token from this method. It logs fine using NSLog, but when I use NSString initWithData:, I always get some cryptic thing. I suppose the encoding is wrong?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The token is an NSData object, which points to a raw binary blob of data, not a string. The two most common ways to convert it to a string would be:

1. base64 encode it
   Download http://projectswithlove.com/projects/NSData_Base64.zip

> ```
> NSString *str = [deviceToken base64EncodedStringWithoutNewlines];
> ```

2. Use NSData's -description to get a string hex dump and clean it up

> ```
> NSString *str = [[deviceToken description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
> str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
> str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
> ```

I prefer #1 because the latter is dependent on the internal way that NSData's -description call works, but either should work.

Comment: I use the base64 method, but use 'url safe' base64 which is an encoding that makes the resulting string acceptable as - is in URLs, etc. The original base64 uses the  '+' and '/' characters of standard Base64 are respectively replaced by '-' and '_'.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the hexadecimal string without worrying about the behaviour of `NSData`'s `description` method, with:

```
+ (NSString *)hexadecimalStringFromData:(NSData *)data {
    NSMutableString *hexToken;
    const unsigned char *iterator = (const unsigned char *) [data bytes];
    if (iterator) {
        hexToken = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            [hexToken appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02lx", (unsigned long) iterator[i]]];
        }
        return hexToken;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Token is NSData.You can convert to string.And remove < and > and spaces

```
NSString *devToken = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
devToken = [devToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];


NSLog(@"token: %@",devToken);
```